# Is using cfc filter available in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, filter, gnuplot, curve

Sorry for a very general topic. Gnuplot is awesome. The only thing I am missing in gnuplot for my casual FEM postprocessing workflow is the use of cfc60, cfc180, cfc600 and cfc1000 filters. Is there a way to implement them? viz 
[image: filters_plot]

Comment: Show your code. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers.

Comment: if you don't have gnuplot code, it would help if you can describe the algorithm (or link to) what calculations need to be done for implementing the CFC-filters.That's what I've found so far. https://www.weisang.com/en/documentation/cfcalgorithm_en# , but I do not yet exactly understand what they mean with "data pass forward and backward". Maybe you can explain?

Comment: ```gnuplot``` is not the recommended tool to achieve this.
Maybe [tag:matlab] or [tag:octave] be more suitable.
[This link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61852-calculate-filter-coefficients-for-phaseless-low-pass-butterworth-filter-compliant-with-sae-j211) can be useful.